# how to send alert to person chosen during the creation of new item in the list in sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint

I am using microsoft office sharepoint server 2007.

i have a sharepoint list in which one collumn is assinged operator. this column selects a single user from a group called operators.

i understand that there is an option to send alert to users using alert me setting of the list. however the problem is that i dont want to send alert to the whole group or to the person i define in alert me settings . i just want the alert to be sent to the person who is selected in the assigned operator column while creating a new item in the list.

how can i do that. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a no-code solution, create a Workflow with Sharepoint Desinger. Follow this tutorial http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointdesigner/HA102390421033.aspx, just when use a field from current list item in the "to" field instead of constnt string.

If you can deploy code to your server, you can create an eventhandler that catches `ItemAdded` event and send your e-mail from code.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a workflow to send email on new operator assigning.

Comment: can you refer me to some link or advice how ?